# Can i set particular byte in string?

Tags: erlang

I have very long string returned from os:cmd. My exe-file output contains some symbols with code 4, so i replaced them with other symbol and put meta in the beginning of the output. Now i want to replace symbols back. How i can do it in quickest way?

Comment: some code, plus command output would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erlang strings are lists. Erlang lists are immutable. So you can't change particular bytes within a string, you can only generate another string with these bytes replaced.

Either replace the characters again (using `map`), or pass the original string around.

Answer (score 2):

I'm an Erlang noob, so this answer is most likely not the best answer.  There's probably a function that does this in a chapter I haven't reached yet in the Erlang Programming book.  However, I think this does what you want:

```
-module(replace).
-export([replace/3]).

replace([], _, _) -> [];
replace([OldChar | T], OldChar, NewChar) -> [NewChar | replace(T, OldChar, NewChar)];
replace([H | T], OldChar, NewChar) -> [H | replace(T, OldChar, NewChar)].
```

It just goes through list (your string) and replaces the old character with the new one.  It doesn't handle I18N.  There are probably faster ways to do this.  It will let you do this:

```
24> replace:replace([48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57], 53, 45).
"01234-6789"
```

or this:

```
28> replace:replace("39582049867", 57, 45).
"3-58204-867"
```

In terms of the quickest way - I'm going to guess that would be a provided function.  If not, you'll have to code it up different ways and run the numbers.

Comment: It doesn't really replace the character but returns a new string with the character replaced.

Comment: @rvirding Well, since data is immutable you can't really change it inline. That's why you need to replace the string with a new one.